# TinyMCE v6 - Insert image as base64

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce-6

With v5 of TinyMCE I can use the following code to insert an image as a base64 string into the editor:

```
tinymce.init({
    paste_data_images: true,
    plugins: 'image imagetools',
    selector: '#editor',
    smart_paste: true,
    toolbar: 'image',
    file_picker_types: 'image',
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success) {
        success('data:' + blobInfo.blob().type + ';base64,' + blobInfo.base64());
    }                  
});
```

The documentation for v6 specifies images_upload_handler now returns a promise, but I can't get it working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The [documentation has an example](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/file-image-upload/#images_upload_handler) how the handler has to be used/how it should work. The handler has to return a `Promise` that resolves with the URL of the image.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However, this example basically uploads the image to the server and requires server-side action. Furthermore, I don't see how this would insert the image into the text area.
The code I'm using with v5 encodes the image to base64 in the browser and inserts it as an image tag, e.g. <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg=="/>
How can I achieve this with v6?